# The current path, % url 'accounts:logout' %, didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-authentication

So, everything in my newly started Django project is working fine except this logout url. I'm using django=1.11.17 and python 3. When I try to logout from the accounts, this is the error I get.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/%25%20url%20'accounts:logout'%20%25
Using the URLconf defined in conspiverse_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^$ [name='home']
^test/$ [name='test']
^thanks/$ [name='thanks']
^admin/
^accounts/
^accounts/
The current path, % url 'accounts:logout' %, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

**accounts/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r"login/$", auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="accounts/login.html"),name='login'),
    url(r"logout/$", auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name="thanks.html"), name="logout"),
    url(r"signup/$", views.SignUp.as_view(), name="signup"),
]
```

**project/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^$", views.HomePage.as_view(), name="home"),
    url(r"^test/$", views.TestPage.as_view(), name="test"),
    url(r"^thanks/$", views.ThanksPage.as_view(), name="thanks"),
    url(r"^admin/", admin.site.urls),
    url(r"^accounts/", include("accounts.urls", namespace="accounts")),
    url(r"^accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
]
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')]

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'test'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'thanks'
```

I tried verifying the URL paths, cross-checked almost everything, it is driving me crazy. Huge thanks for the help!

Comment: since you already declare the name of that url you don't need the account part, just use `href="{% url 'logout' %}"` in your html

Comment: What @Linh Nguyen suggested is almost certainly your issue but it may be helpful if you show us the relevant portion of the template you're clicking to get to the logout page.

Comment: @LinhNguyen Thanks for the help! The problem was something else, due to your comment I just went through my html files again and noticed that my logout href line was missing a pair of curly braces {}, so added that and it works now. So, thanks for your help, helped me finding out the exact problem.